# how to do a proper recursion in GUI with ValueError exception

Tags: python, exception

when I run my program, I get an input from the user and then assign it to the "dimensions" variable. The input needs to be only an integer, I raise an exception for a ValueError and it works and tells the user that it's not an integer. But the code continues through to the next lines to the 'if' statements where the variable dimensions needs to be assigned an integer by now, and reads an error in the console saying 'dimensions is not assigned' 
my question is that how can I make it recursive when the exception is raised so the code does not follow through to the next part until an integer is entered. 
When working within the console I can make it recursive by calling the function again, and here I try to call the funnction again but that doesn't seem to help.

```
def grid_dimensions(self) :
    global dimensions

### Assigns the value entered by the user to a variable for grid dimensions.
    try :
        dimensions = int(self.dimension_entry_box.get())

    except ValueError :
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error:', 'Input is not an Integer!')
        self.new_game()

### checks if the dimensions entered by the user are within the specified values,
### maximum or minimum dimensions if true displays a message to the user. 
    if (dimensions < gomoku_grid.MIN_DIMENSIONS or dimensions > gomoku_grid.MAX_DIMENSIONS) :
        self.message_label['text'] = "Invalid Dimensions - must be 5-16"
        return  
    else :
        self.log_grid = Gum_Gum_Grid(dimensions)
```

Also another part of the game when it's trying to load by accepting a string(filename) from the user I raise an IOError with the same problem, I need it to display the message but not do anything until it get's the correct filename.

```
    except IOError : 
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error:', 'Filename not recognized')
        self.get_load_string()
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `except` *after* the code that must not happen if there's an exception. If you read what you've written you say try something, catch an exception if there is one, then do the `if...else` regardless:

```
def grid_dimensions(self) :
    global dimensions

    ### Assigns the value entered by the user to a variable for grid dimensions.
    try :
        dimensions = int(self.dimension_entry_box.get())


        ### checks if the dimensions entered by the user are within the specified values,
        ### maximum or minimum dimensions if true displays a message to the user. 
        if (dimensions < gomoku_grid.MIN_DIMENSIONS or dimensions > gomoku_grid.MAX_DIMENSIONS) :
            self.message_label['text'] = "Invalid Dimensions - must be 5-16"
            return  
        else :
            self.log_grid = Gum_Gum_Grid(dimensions)

    ### Note - Moved
    except ValueError :
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error:', 'Input is not an Integer!')
        self.new_game()
```

Comment: This still didn't fix the error. the code continues to the if statement without an integer. 
thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming self.dimension_entry_box.get() prompts the user for a value, try something like:

```
while True:
    try :
        dimensions = int(self.dimension_entry_box.get())
        break
    except ValueError :
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error:', 'Input is not an Integer!')
```

this also avoids catching `ValueError`s caused by anything but the invalid input.

Comment: Thannks for the input, but i tried this and the console still continues to read the code and realizes dimensions is not defined.  In python 3 is there a way to make an if statement that will say: "If dimensions is not an integer display this error else contnue" meaning a way to compare the variable and check if its an integer?

Comment: Hopefully you removed the recursion when replacing it with the above while-loop?